# Getting application link from Google Play before upload

Tags: java, android

I have an item in my navigation drawer called "share app" which users can use to share application link to other users.
My question is, can i get the link without first uploading to google play. I don't intend to re-upload my app in other to apply this functionality.
I have tried searching for this answer without any meaningful solution.

```
   try {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
                String sAux = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
                sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.ben.example \n\n";
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.toString();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play store links are deterministic. Your link should look like this :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename

**Edit**
To know your package name, search for package in manifest tag : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: do u mean something like this?  "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.leavenotes"??

Comment: Yes something like this. There is a %22 at the end of the link. A stray quotes ? Hope it's not intentional.

Comment: you mean after the quotes?

Comment: pls review my updated code in my question to see if i implemented it correctly. i appreciate ur assistance

Comment: Yes your link format is correct. However you don't need to be this worried. You should first launch alpha, then beta then production... By then you will surely get a proper URL without even making a release. And even if things go bad still, you can immediately build a new apk and upload within minutes of last upload. It won't affect your users much.